# Spring systemProperties not appending value properly

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring 3.1 to create a bean in an web application like below wherein the server contains -DCONFIG_MODE=dev. However, it seems spring is only resolving the filename to configuration.dev without appending the remaining .xml. Could you please point what could be wrong in this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core"
   xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                       http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core.xsd
                       http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd">

   <bean id="xmlConfig" class="org.quwic.itms.mq.XmlConfiguration" init-method="init">
       <constructor-arg type="java.net.URL" value="classpath:configuration.#{systemProperties.CONFIG_MODE}.xml"/>
       <constructor-arg type="org.apache.commons.configuration.reloading.ReloadingStrategy" ref="reloadingStrategy"/>
  </bean>

    <!-- The managed reloading strategy for the configuration bean -->
    <bean id="reloadingStrategy" class="org.apache.commons.configuration.reloading.FileChangedReloadingStrategy">
        <property name="refreshDelay" value="300000"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Could you edit your post to show the application context xml?

Comment: It seems to be very unlikely... are you 100% sure it does not contain the `.xml` suffix?

Comment: I have added the applicationContext.xml file. The error I am getting is "class path resource [configuration.dev -Dprogram.name=JBossTools: JBoss 5.0 Runtime.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. I wrongly specified the system property as "-DCONFIG_MODE=local -Dprogram.name=JBossTools: JBoss 5.0 Runtime" rather than -DCONFIG_MODE=local "-Dprogram.name=JBossTools: JBoss 5.0 Runtime"